# Integrating frameworks without bloating the size of iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks, ondemand

Is there a way to avoid bloating of my app in appstore if my app wants to support more integrations. For example i have 10 barocde integartions done in my app either as a single framework or multiple frameworks. But the user needs only one integration out of 10. So is there a way to provide the only integration required by him without unnecessarily downloading all 10 integrations either though on-demand or achieving it through inter app communication by providing each integrations as a separate app and communicating between them without any hassle or anything like services in android can be achieved in iOS so that service will run at background and broadcasts the data to the app once it receives.

Comment: i think it would only be possible through on demand resources

Comment: @Scriptable But is there any possibility of making framewroks as on-demand resources? As per my knowledge on-demand can only be done for assets right?

Comment: actually thinking about it a bit more, i dont think it would be possible. the code is compiled against those libraries and you have the import statements to load the libraries as well as the linking that takes place during compilation.

Comment: @Scriptable what if i use dynamic frameworks. As it loads during run time, will it be possible to replace the dynamic framework in its path which has no changes in its public headers(interface) but has some extended support in its private methods. If this can be achieved, can make the application work fine with the extended support in its framework as there is no changes in its public interface. Any ideas on this?

Comment: it might be possible, I can imagine it probably is achievable but it wont be easy. I haven't done it before so I couldn't say for sure. I will look into it though, it's an interesting concept

Comment: @Scriptable Thanks for your replies. If you find it possible, kindly make an update.